# java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed

Tags: java, android, android-camera, runtimeexception

when i do continuous click on Capture button (without any break), getting Runtime Exception
how can i resolve this issue ?

if its not possible so how may i handle this Exception ?

```
btnCapture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(CameraLauncherActivity.this, R.raw.button);
                btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                            // line where getting RuntimeException
                        camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);   

                    }
                });
```

**Log:**

```
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1126)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1071)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at app.cam.shane.CameraLauncherActivity$3.onClick(CameraLauncherActivity.java:116)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
02-12 14:48:41.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6997):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Note:-** Like in **Pudding Camera**, they allow user to do continuous tap on Capture button, but they will never show exception, if you do 50 clicks it will capture 10 or more images, each image after specific time but not showing exception, like i am getting in my code, in a same way how can i handle this exception ?

**Complete Code:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);     
            previewHolder=preview.getHolder();    
            previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);    
            previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

            btnCapture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(CameraLauncherActivity.this, R.raw.button);
            btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mp.start();
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);                 
                }
            });


    @Override
    public void onResume() {  
        super.onResume();   
        camera=Camera.open(); 
    }  

    @Override   
    public void onPause() {  
        super.onPause();  
        if (inPreview) {  
        camera.stopPreview();   
        }   
        camera.release();   
        camera=null;   
        inPreview=false;         
    }   


    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
            Camera.Parameters parameters) {
            Camera.Size result=null;

            for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
                if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
                    if (result == null) {
                        result=size;
                    }
                    else {
                        int resultArea=result.width * result.height;
                        int newArea=size.width * size.height;

                        if (newArea > resultArea) {
                            result=size;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return(result);
        }

    private Camera.Size getSmallestPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result=null;

        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
            if (result == null) {
                result=size;
            }
            else {
                int resultArea=result.width * result.height;
                int newArea=size.width * size.height;

                if (newArea < resultArea) {
                    result=size;
                }
            }
        }

        return(result);
    }


    SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {     
        try {        
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder); 
            }   catch (Throwable t) {   
                Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
                        "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
                Toast.makeText(CameraLauncherActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
                }     
            }      

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format, int width,int height) {
        params = camera.getParameters();       
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, params);  
        Camera.Size pictureSize=getSmallestPictureSize(params);
        if (size != null && pictureSize != null) {      
            params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
            params.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width,
                    pictureSize.height);
            camera.setParameters(params);       
            camera.startPreview();       
            inPreview=true;                 

            }     
        }      

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }   
    };       

    PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            camera.startPreview();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    static File getOutputMediaFile() {

        /* yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ */
        timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
        .format(new Date());

        // file name
        mediaFile = new File(LoginActivity.mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;

    }


}
```

Comment: Did you add required permissions in the manifest?

Comment: everything works fine just want to do control on continuous click and want to control over exception

Comment: U have to call `startPreview()` after `takePicture()`

Comment: 1. Please add onPictureTaken() code in your question. 2. When is onTouchEvent() used? 3. Do you want to take picture by pressing button only? 4. Is RuntimeException happening if you press the button once?

Comment: @Melquiades hello bro i posted complete code please check now, getting RuntimeException when pressing multiple times without any break otherwise works fine

Comment: You could use flag to limit calling takePicture() to the speed with which your images are being saved. More details in the answer.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Firstly, catch your exceptions in onPictureTaken, leaving empty catch sections is not a good practice. Then, I would add a flag that would prevent from calling takePicture() while previous picture is being saved. Later in your button onClick you would check if it's ok to call takePicture().

1. Declare a flag as a member of your Activity:

   ```
   private boolean safeToTakePicture = false;
   ```
2. In `surfaceChanged()`, just set the flag to true after calling startPreview():

   ```
   camera.startPreview();
   safeToTakePicture = true;
   ```
3. In your `onClick()` listener check the flag and take picture if ok to do so:

   ```
   if (safeToTakePicture) {
       mp.start();
       camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture); 
       safeToTakePicture = false;
   }
   ```
4. In `onPictureTaken()`, set the flag again to true after picture has been saved (and add exception printing):

   ```
   PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
           pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
           camera.startPreview();

           if (pictureFile == null) {
               //no path to picture, return
               safeToTakePicture = true;
               return;
           }
           try {
               FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
               fos.write(data);
               fos.close();

           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();              //<-------- show exception
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();              //<-------- show exception
           }

           //finished saving picture 
           safeToTakePicture = true;
       }
   };
   ```

**NOTES:**
As the docs say, **"Preview must be started before you can take a picture."**, so possible enhancement would be to use setPreviewCallback() to register callback that will be called when preview data is available, and set the flag to true when onPreviewFrame is called.

Comment: such a amazing solution :) you are just genius.. nice explanation, and one small question what if i also want to use Camera's default button to capture image, like in pudding camera

Comment: why my implement method didt call it start ? :( surfaceChanged()

Comment: @Melquiades  this code is not working inside Thread and i m getting exception http://pastie.org/9583142   its taking fist image fine but after first image it gets crashed

Comment: @ErumHannan, can you post a new question on SO with your code, and notify me, I'll have a look.

Comment: i have resolved this issue but still after taking pictures in loop i m starting another activity but from new activity when trying to hit back key to move back towards camera activity its crashing my app because onStop has been called and it releases the camera but onStart i have start the camera again but its not working @Melquiades

Comment: can u pls continue discussion here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow

Comment: I used Camera.setPreviewCallback()..it worked fine for me...thanks Melquiades

Comment: calling `camera.startPreview()` before `takePicture` did the trick!

Comment: @Melquiades What is mp?

Comment: @SoftDev MediaPlayer - see in original question

Answer (score 9):

I also had the similar issue. later i found `startPreview` is very important.

`_camera.startPreview()` is very important before the takePicutre checkout the point 5 and 6
[in this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).

Comment: before takePicture(..) where in onTouchEvent(,..) or capture button ?

Comment: @Sun yes, you need to call camera.startPreview() when the saving job is done (eg. in onPictureTaken()), else the camera won't allow you to take another image

Answer (score 7):

There can be many reasons for this in my case i was trying to take photo without preview (hidden photo) and i was using `SurfaceView`, So i replaced it with `SurfaceTexture`

```
SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(10);
camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
```

and the problem was solved... 
P.S I was getting this error only on Above 6.0 devices

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to call `startPreview()` on the Camera?

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This method will help you in trying to solve the problem.

```
private void safeCameraOpen(int id) {

        try {
            releaseCameraAndPreview();
            mCamera = Camera.open(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
```