# FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to capture a picture without previewing the camera. I have referred to many articles and some of them are:

http://cell0907.blogspot.in/2014/01/android-camera-capture-without.html

http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/implement-takepicture-function-of.html

I have added the permissions for Camera and writing to external storage.

In the xml of my activity, i'm using a `surfaceView` component whose width and height is 1dp. Also there is a button, and onclick of this button, a pic has to be captured. Below is the code for my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CameraActivity"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="capture" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now referring to the above mentioned links i have performed the following in the corresponding Activity file:

```
package com.samplecamera;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.text.format.DateFormat;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

        SurfaceView sv=null;
        Camera cam=null;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

            cam=Camera.open();
            sv=(SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);

            try {  
                cam.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());  
           } catch (IOException e) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                e.printStackTrace();  
           }  

             cam.startPreview();  
             Camera.Parameters params = cam.getParameters();  
             params.setJpegQuality(100);  
             cam.setParameters(params);

             Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
             btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      cam.startPreview();
                      cam.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
                }
            });

        }

        Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {  
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {  
               //decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap  
                  //display.setImageBitmap(photo);  
                 // Bitmap bitmapPicture  
                //  = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);  
                  FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+
                                DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_kk-mm-ss", new Date().getTime())+".jpeg");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    try {
                        fos.write(data);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  
             }        
       }; 

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cam.release();
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.camera, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Onclick of the button i get the following exception:

```
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1163)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1108)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at com.samplecamera.CameraActivity$2.onClick(CameraActivity.java:55)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16987)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
03-21 11:55:44.404: E/AndroidRuntime(27544):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help regarding the same.

Comment: which is your onClick(CameraActivity.java:55)

Comment: @GauravPandey: Thanks for the reply. I have put the entire code here. So since i have only one button, there is only one onclick in the above example.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723557/java-lang-runtimeexception-takepicture-failed

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cam.startpreview() function from onclick event and while doing coding for media related projects try to check camera==null and then move further,by using this your code will not get crash

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the change you asked me to, it doesnt work.