# Sony Xperia M takePicture() always crash

Tags: android, sony-xperia

I'm building an Camera application for Sony Xperia M C1905
User press a button to take picture then save.
Problem start when i call takePicture() outside autoFocusCallback

Is this Sony specific problem or i am doing something wrong here ?

Here's the logcat output :

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.IllegalStateException:+Could+not+execute+method+of+the+activity
    at+android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3671)
    at+android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4171)
    at+android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17195)
    at+android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:643)
    at+android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at+android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at+android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
    at+java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native+Method)
    at+java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at+com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at+com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at+dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native+Method)
Caused+by:+java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at+java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native+Method)
    at+java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at+android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3666)
    ...+11+more
Caused+by:+java.lang.RuntimeException:+takePicture+failed
    at+android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native+Method)
    at+android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1117)
    at+ims.alpha.moses.MainActivity.camerabuttonClicked(MainActivity.java:221)
    ...+14+more
java.lang.RuntimeException:+takePicture+failed
    at+android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native+Method)
    at+android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1117)
    at+ims.alpha.moses.MainActivity.camerabuttonClicked(MainActivity.java:221)
    at+java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native+Method)
    at+java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at+android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3666)
    at+android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4171)
    at+android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17195)
    at+android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:643)
    at+android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at+android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at+android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
    at+java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native+Method)
    at+java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at+com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at+com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at+dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native+Method)
&PHONE_MODEL=C1905&ANDROID_VERSION=4.1.2
```

Here's the relevant code :

```
public PictureCallback jpgCallback = new PictureCallback() {            
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // do processing here
    }
};

// Sony Xperia M device constantly crash when takepicture is called from outside AutoFocusCallback
public AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new AutoFocusCallback() {        
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        if (success) {
            Globals.myCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpgCallback);
        } else {

        }
    }
};
```

This code works :

```
public void camerabuttonClicked(View v) {
    Globals.myCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);      
    Globals.myCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
}
```

This code constantly crashed the app :

```
public void camerabuttonClicked(View v) {
    Globals.myCamera.stopPreview();     
    Globals.myCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpgCallback); // MainActivity.java:221
}
```

I also tested this code on Samsung Galaxy S2 and it doesn't have this problem. It doesn't matter where i called the takePicture() from.

Comment: You're calling stopPreview just before taking the picture.  The camera *must be showing a preview before takePicture is called*. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723557/java-lang-runtimeexception-takepicture-failed

Comment: It worked, sorry i didn't know that.

Comment: No need to apologize.  Just need to be careful when reading the documentation.  Particularly with the Camera API which is a pretty rough at times.