# My application crashes in some devices when I try to take a picture in background

Tags: android, camera

I am making an app to take pictures in background. When I try this in a Samsung S3 device everything works and I do not get any errors, but when I try it with a Samsung S4 i receive the following:

```
04-05 15:07:56.379    9351-9351/com.parse.starter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 9351
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.parse.starter.camera.TakePhoto@42c6fc48 with Intent { cmp=com.parse.starter/.camera.TakePhoto }: java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2877)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
            at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
            at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1341)
            at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1286)
            at com.parse.starter.camera.TakePhoto.run(TakePhoto.java:69)
            at com.parse.starter.camera.TakePhoto.onStartCommand(TakePhoto.java:42)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2860)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the code that I use to take the picture:(its a service not an Activity)

```
   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        id = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getObjectId();
        // do we have a camera?
        type = intent.getBooleanExtra("Location", false);
        if (!getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        } else {
            cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId < 0) {
            } else {
                camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
            }
        }
        run(); 
               final Handler cameraHandler = new Handler();
    cameraHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            onPause();
            if (type)stopSelf();
        }
    }, 5000)

        return 1;
    }

public void run() {
        camera.takePicture(null, null,
                new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext(), id));
    }
protected void onPause() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }
```

and the `PhotoHandler.java`:

```
@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFileDir = getDir();

        if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

            Log.d(TakePhoto.DEBUG_TAG, "Can't create directory to save image.");
            return;

        }

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

        String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;


        pictureFile = new File(filename); 


        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close(); 
        } catch (Exception error) {
        }
    }

private File getDir() {
        File sdDir = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return new File(sdDir, "Camera");
    }
```

Here is a Log when I run it on a S3:

```
04-05 15:41:35.690  20278-20278/com.parse.starter I/PUSH﹕ Received
04-05 15:41:35.710  20278-20278/com.parse.starter D/MakePhotoActivity﹕ Camera found
04-05 15:41:36.140  20278-20278/com.parse.starter D/PHOTO﹕ /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Camera/Picture_20154105034136.jpg
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

 <service android:name=".camera.TakePhoto" />
```

Comment: Did you Google your problem?

Comment: @GaurawYadav I have been doing that for the 2 hours now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723557/java-lang-runtimeexception-takepicture-failed

Comment: @GaurawYadav I saw this one, but I dont want for the app to have a preview, and the problem is that it is working fine on S3 device but not on a S4

Comment: have you declared your service in your manifest? `com.parse.starter.camera.TakePhoto`

Comment: You can not take a picture without preview.

Comment: @Blundell yes I have, as I have mentioned above this works fine on my S3 device but when I tried on a S4 for gives the above error

Comment: Are you taking one picture or a series of pictures? That run() is a method of which/what?

Comment: @GaurawYadav but the same code works fine on a S3

Comment: and `TakePhoto.java:69` is the line you show above in the `run` method? Do you call `.close()` on your camera at some point. If you restart your device does it work once and then not work again? If so you are not obtaining and releasing the camera correctly

Comment: @greenapps  I have edited the above code for the run() method, I only want to take one picture when a notification is sent to the device

Comment: But now you took that run() out with the code to take a picture!? You are calling run() and onPause() ? At the same time?

Comment: @Blundell I edited the code now to show the whole class

Comment: Should one call run() and onPause() ?

Comment: @greenapps because I call this service many times I have to release the camera after each use otherwise the app would crash

Comment: Can you show androidmanifest.xml?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I added the permissions and the service I have declared in the manifest

Comment: you should not call `onPause` straight after run, like I said above you're doing it wrong so the camera is not in the right state

Comment: @Blundell I added a handler so it delays the call of `onPause` but still I get the same error. Is it possible for the issue to be at the device instead of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is crashing when you call `camera.takePicure()`

From the java doc of this method [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback))

> This method is only valid when preview is active (after startPreview()). Preview will be stopped after the image is taken; callers must call startPreview() again if they want to re-start preview or take more pictures. This should not be called between start() and stop().

**I do not see you using a preview anywhere**?

You will need to `startPreview` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#startPreview()

I see you are trying to take a picture in the background (so don't show the user a preview). You can do this, you just need to set a dummy surface, I explain how to do this here, you just have to ignore the bit about the face detection.

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-front-camera-face-detection-explained/

To fix your code above:

1) Create a DummySurface that will show the preview (but the user will not see this). https://github.com/blundell/FaceDetectionTutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blundell/tutorial/cam/DummySurfaceHolder.java

2) Set the `DummySurface` on your `camera` and call `startPreview`

```
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(new DummyHolder());
        camera.startPreview();
```