# How capture photo of camera periodically from service?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I want capture periodically photo of camera from a service and send throught socket to server application (desktop software), then i tried make this with code below, but only a capture is done and not continues capturing.

Based in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940274/9672569) i must define `startPreview()` before of capture with `takePicture()` then i'm already making this, but even so not works.

Someone could help me please?

```
package com.example.vrs.myexampleapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

import static android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MyCamera extends Service {

    public final int DONE = 1;
    public final int NEXT = 2;
    public final int PERIOD = 1000;
    private Camera camera;
    private Timer timer;
    private int cameraId = 0;
    SurfaceHolder previewHolder;

    public class Timer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        Context mContext;
        private Handler threadHandler;

        public Timer(Context context, Handler threadHandler) {
            super();
            this.threadHandler = threadHandler;
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(PERIOD);
                Message.obtain(threadHandler, DONE, "").sendToTarget();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                Log.i("MyCamera", "Camera found");
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    public void startCamera() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

            cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId < 0) {
                Log.i("MyCamera", "No front facing camera found.");
            } else {
                safeCameraOpen(cameraId);
            }

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                SurfaceView dummy = new SurfaceView(this);
                previewHolder = dummy.getHolder();

                previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(MODE_PRIVATE);
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            camera.startPreview();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setJpegQuality(100);
            camera.setParameters(params);

            timer = new Timer(getApplicationContext(), threadHandler);
            timer.execute();
        }
    }

    public static DataOutputStream dos;
    public static byte[] array;

    private Handler threadHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case DONE:
                    camera.startPreview();
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
                    break;
                case NEXT:
                    Log.i("MyCamera", "Here in NEXT!!");
                    timer = new Timer(getApplicationContext(), threadHandler);
                    timer.execute();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            Log.i("MyCamera", "Here in PictureCallback");

            if (data != null) {

                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.postRotate(270);

                Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                bitmapPicture = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapPicture, 360, 360, true);
                Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPicture, 0, 0, bitmapPicture.getWidth(), bitmapPicture.getHeight(), mtx, true);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                try {

                    rotatedBMP.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                    array = Methods.compress(bos.toByteArray());

                    new ConnAsyncTask().execute();
                    Message.obtain(threadHandler, NEXT, "").sendToTarget(); // Capture a new photo

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        }
    };

    static class ConnAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                dos = new DataOutputStream(SocketBackgroundService.yclientSocket.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeInt(array.length);
                dos.write(array, 0, array.length);
                dos.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
        boolean qOpened = false;
        try {
            stopCamera();
            camera = Camera.open(id);
            qOpened = (camera != null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("MyCamera", "failed to open Camera");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return qOpened;
    }

    public void stopCamera() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    public static MyCamera instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.i("MyCamera", "Service created!!!");
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i("MyCamera", "onStartCommand() service started!!!");

        instance = this;

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `threadHandler.postDelayed()` instead of your Timer AsyncTask? Also, is your callback actually called every time? You have a log there; does it log when it should?

Comment: @TheWanderer, this line `Log.i("MyCamera", "Here in NEXT!!");` is executed only one time, but `timer.execute();` not re-executes the `Timer AsyncTask`.

Comment: Again, you shouldn't be using an AsyncTask for a simple delay. That's why Handler.postDelayed exists.

Comment: @TheWanderer, thank you, `Handler.postDelayed()` solved the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you're using an AsyncTask (your Timer class) for a delay.

Replace that with a simple `handler.postDelayed()`.